# Pushing your hydrophone to the limit

Tags: hydrophone, contact-mic, microphone-technique

Who has risked their microphone investment and have it pay off?

- Submerged in boiling water
- Frozen in ice
- Dipped in liquids other than water,
  ie. syrup, molasses, oil, etc
- Floated close to hazardous objects,
  ie. garbage disposal blades,
  propellors, etc
- Something else even crazier than the
  above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of mine built a hydrophone then froze it into a lake - in north sweden. you can hear the results from here: 
http://www.riwid.net/works/singing-ice/

Comment: @Richard, great link. I'd love to hear high-res clips of that recording, if possible. Contact me via LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not THAT extreme, but I did bury my hydrophone in my compost pile. It's out on loan, but I figure I'd need to let it sit for a few days before recording with it, and then would need to do so for a few hours to see what I could get...the initial session was too short to get much cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Just found [this](http://www.sonic-terrain.com/2010/09/recording-of-the-week-maggots-fun-by-richard-devine/) on the Sonic-Terrain site. Definitely applies to this topic.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of.

Comment: That sound is 100X worse than the worst mouth noise I have ever heard.

Answer (score 1):

While I take no credit for doing it, an old friend of mine submerged one in his bathtub and fired off a bottle rocket.  Him, the mic, and the bathtub/apartment survived.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit more of a joke... but this dog was seriously psycho! And it obsessed over the fluffy a little too much. Got a few nips too. The sound was was what I needed so it paid off.

oops, just read "hydrophone" in the title... I always post quicker than I read. In anycase it was so slobbery, that I probably needed a hydrophone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting the hydrophone inside a balloon filled with water to get interesting impacts, jiggles, etc., but unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to avoid cable vibration/noise emanating from where it touched the tied neck of the balloon. Made some interesting sound though.